# Duplicate ID in the database

Tags: sql, database, duplicates

I noticed in my database, some users have the same `ID` number (it seems to be a bug that didn't check if the `id` number was already taken for a deleted user).

There are hundreds of couples of users with the same `ID` number.

Through SQL I would like to update (adding a 0) to all those users who have a duplicate `ID` and are deleted.

I'm very familiar with the SQL language. 
I found all the duplicate ID users using this query, but I am not sure how I should proceed.

```sql
SELECT ID, COUNT(*) As Num 
FROM Users
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(ID) >= 2
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Do you otherwise have a primary key?  Sample data and the table definition would help.

Comment: Should leverage the functionality of unique or primary key constraints for the tables to deter the possibility of duplicate records.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have some sort of "isdeleted" flag.  Although I'm not sure that "adding a zero" is the best solution to your problem, the standard SQL for this would, based on your description, look something like this:

```
update t
    set id = id || '0'
    where isdeleted = 1 and
          exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.id = t.id and t2.isdeleted = 0);
```

This assumes that `isdeleted` is a number, with `0` for false and `1` for true.  `||` is the standard SQL operator for string concatenation.  Some databases have other mechanisms for string concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

The query is for oracle, not sure what database are you using,

```
update users set id = id||0 where rowid not in 
(select max(rowid ) from users group by id)
--and flag = 'Deleted Flag'  -- uncomment the delete flag if you have in the table. If not just use same query a it is
;
```